# Apache hadoop Yarn example program

Tags: apache, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am new to Apache YARN. I have installed the Apache YARN.Now what i need is, a sample program to test the installation. Can you please tell me the program location (except Hortonworks YARN examples). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use provided examples in jar file located at `$Yarn_Home/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-0.23.1.jar`.

example:

`yarn jar $Yarn_Home/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-0.23.1.jar wordcount /in /out`

`/in` and `/out` are located in hdfs. You need to put some text files in `/in` and `/out` must not exist before.

Comment: Those are mapreduce examples. Can you say some Yarn application codes ?

Comment: Are you looking for codes other than examples like [wordcount](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount)?

Comment: Yes similar to wordcount examples. But those codes give are only mapreduce programs not YARN applications.

Comment: There is no much difference.

Comment: Here is a [sample yarn application](https://github.com/hortonworks/simple-yarn-app) by hortonworks.